# Should I ask permission of my co-authors when republishing an article?

Tags: publications, authorship

In the university that I am working, which is more technically than research oriented, they want me to publish one of my past articles in a faculty magazine that they are planning to print. I have chosen one from the IEEE, and I have read that they have that possibility. I would like to know if I should mention that to my other co-authors or is it not necessary?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

As a courtesy, one should always inform co-authors of such things. One doesn't necessarily expect replies (since no action is required...), but one is taking action on "property" that is partially "owned" by other people, so some notification, or even request for permission (which would presumably be unhesitatingly granted), is entirely reasonable.

Comment: in other words, if "your" paper has co-authors, it's not really "yours" :)

Comment: I thoroughly agree, and this issue can arise even with a single author.  One of my papers was reprinted in a book without anyone telling me.  (The publisher gave the book's editors legal permission to reprint it, and I guess the publisher thought the editors had already discussed it with me, while the editors assumed the publisher would notify me.)  This didn't cause much harm, but it did embarrass me a little: the first time anyone asked me about the book, I confidently explained that they must be thinking of someone else's paper.